# Visualizing graph with Graphviz

Tags: image, graph, error-handling, graphviz

I want to visualize a graph with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) on Windows and found the program GVEdit. I wanted to test this command:

```
digraph graphname { 
    a -> b -> c;
    b -> d;
}
```

and get following message from GVEdit:

```
Error: <gvedit>: syntax error in line 1 near 'digraph'
```

Whzt does this error mean, and how can I create Graphs from a text visualized? Is GVEdit the right program?

Comment: I saved the `.dot` file above and could open it successfully in GVEdit 1.01 running on Windows 7 without the error that you have reported. Are you sure that you are trying to open this file and not another? For example, I can replicate the error message if I try to open a file that contains only `digraph digraph`.

Comment: Try yo save as ASCII file. The earliest version may have problem with UTF8 text files. http://www.graphviz.org/mantisbt/view.php?id=1591 That also implies you are using an extremely old version, say earlier than April 2009.

Comment: Same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645375/i-want-to-use-graphviz-but-error-syntax-error-in-line-1-near