# i want to use graphviz ,but error 'syntax error in line 1 near '{''

Tags: macos, graphviz, dot

i use macOS

already $ brew install graphviz

so, i  can use dot -V

⇨ dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)

i made [test.dot] file on Desktop,and dot -T png -O test.dot
but , Error: test.dot: syntax error in line 1 near '{' occured

please help

test.dot

```
digraph d {
 A [label="Hello"]
 B [label="World"]
 C [label="Everyone"]
 A -> { B C }
}
```

As a matter of concern, opening a file opens in a word

Comment: What mean "file opens in a word"? `test.dot` must be plain text file. Your example are processed by graphviz without any problems.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to line endings or BOM markers. I get

```
$ cat PruneGraph.dot  | dot.exe
Error: <stdin>: syntax error in line 1 near 'digraph'
```

but the following fixes it:

```
$ cat PruneGraph.dot | dos2unix.exe  | dot.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your example in different environments. The example is valid. As user882813 stated, it could be that your file is not plain ASCII and there are special character you probably not see directly. Use a plain ASCI-Editor, for e.g. vscode, and try again.